# como edito el metodo initiComponents en java con Netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans

tengo un form en java netbeans, y acabo de eliminar un botón que ya no necesito
el problema es que no lo elimine correctamente y  me marca un error en el metodo initComponents

como puedo editar el InitComponents para borrar ese codigo?

```
 private void initComponents() {

    panHuellas = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    lblImagenHuella = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    panBtns = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jPanel2 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    btnSalir = new javax.swing.JButton();
    btnIdentificar = new javax.swing.JButton();
    btnGuardar = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jPanel4 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    txtArea = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
    jPanel3 = new javax.swing.JPanel();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    setTitle("************************************************");
    setResizable(false);
    addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {
        public void windowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {
            formWindowClosing(evt);
        }
        public void windowOpened(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {
            formWindowOpened(evt);
        }
    });

    panHuellas.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(null, "Huella Digital Capturada", javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.CENTER, javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.DEFAULT_POSITION));
    panHuellas.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(400, 270));
    panHuellas.setLayout(new java.awt.BorderLayout());

    jPanel1.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(javax.swing.border.BevelBorder.LOWERED));
    jPanel1.setLayout(new java.awt.BorderLayout());
    jPanel1.add(lblImagenHuella, java.awt.BorderLayout.CENTER);

    panHuellas.add(jPanel1, java.awt.BorderLayout.CENTER);

    getContentPane().add(panHuellas, java.awt.BorderLayout.NORTH);

    panBtns.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(null, "Acciones", javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.CENTER, javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.DEFAULT_POSITION));
    panBtns.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(400, 190));
    panBtns.setLayout(new java.awt.BorderLayout());

    jPanel2.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(366, 90));

    btnSalir.setText("Salir");
    btnSalir.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            btnSalirActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    btnIdentificar.setText("Identificar");
    btnIdentificar.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(71, 23));
    btnIdentificar.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            **btnIdentificarActionPerformed(evt);**
        }
    });

    btnGuardar.setText("Guardar");
    btnGuardar.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            btnGuardarActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jButton1.setText("Usuarios");
    jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel2Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel2);
    jPanel2.setLayout(jPanel2Layout);
    jPanel2Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                .addComponent(btnIdentificar, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 139, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 142, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(btnGuardar, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 128, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(btnSalir, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 128, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addContainerGap())
    );
    jPanel2Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                .addComponent(btnGuardar, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 32, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                .addComponent(btnSalir, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 30, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(btnIdentificar, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addGap(3, 3, 3)))
            .addContainerGap())
    );

    panBtns.add(jPanel2, java.awt.BorderLayout.NORTH);

    jPanel4.setLayout(new java.awt.BorderLayout());

    txtArea.setColumns(20);
    txtArea.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Lucida Sans", 1, 10)); // NOI18N
    txtArea.setRows(5);
    jScrollPane1.setViewportView(txtArea);

    jPanel4.add(jScrollPane1, java.awt.BorderLayout.CENTER);

    panBtns.add(jPanel4, java.awt.BorderLayout.CENTER);

    jPanel3.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(366, 20));

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel3Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel3);
    jPanel3.setLayout(jPanel3Layout);
    jPanel3Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 429, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    jPanel3Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 20, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    panBtns.add(jPanel3, java.awt.BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    getContentPane().add(panBtns, java.awt.BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    setSize(new java.awt.Dimension(457, 496));
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
}// </editor-fold>
```

Comment: Podrías anexar el error que te muestra?

Comment: por desgracia ya corregi eso, pero aun asi me gustaria conocer lo que opinas

Comment: me arrojaba el error de object not found, queria eliminar una clase

Answer (score 1):

Desde Netbeans no es posible editar el método `initComponents`, además que no es recomendado en caso de un '*error humano*', sin embargo, si ocurre algún error que Netbeans no pueda corregir (nunca me ha sucedido), puedes usar un editor de texto común y editar las líneas de código en conflicto (al final de la respuesta explico más sobre eso).

Lo que puedes hacer **desde Netbeans** es *personalizar* algunas líneas de código y *agregar* nuevas líneas de los componentes que agregues; sólo bastaría con presionar clic derecho en el componente y seleccionar la opción *Customize Code...*

[image: img1]

Te saldrá una ventana como la de abajo, como notarás escribí algunos comentarios entre líneas, y a su vez se genera un indicador en la parte izquierda del código (`pre-creation`, `pre-init`, ...) que básicamente son para mantener un orden al momento de crear un objeto

[image: img2]

Esos cambios serán reflejos en el método `initComponents`.

---

Por otro lado, y como mencioné al principio, puedes usar un editor de texto común para editar el código generado por Netbeans, no sé hasta qué punto podría ser dañino, pero si necesitas arreglar tu código, podría ayudarte mucho.

Lo único que debes hacer es navegar a la ubicación de tu proyecto, normalmente, los proyectos se ubican en el directorio de `Documentos/NetBeansProjects/TuProyecto`(si no has cambiado su ubicación). Una vez ahí, entra en el directorio **src** y busca el archivo de tu clase (el cual debería tener una extensión `.java`), ese archivo es el que debes abrir con tu editor de texto favorito.

Luego, sólo debes hacer los cambios necesarios y finalmente guardar el archivo, Netbeans actualizará automáticamente el archivo con los cambios. Te dejo un ejemplo:

- Desde mi editor de texto

[image: img3]

- Desde Netbeans

[image: img4]